# Expo android build gives checkReleaseDuplicateClasses Error

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo

I was attempting to build an apk file for android from an expo project using expo buids.

I ran the following command below:

`eas build -p android --profile preview`

After running the command (Works successfully before), I get the following error.

[image]

[image]

I've tried to do multiple fixes:

1. Tried to use node version 16 (since expo migrated to version 18) which was the previous working version but still the same error
2. Tried to revert back to the old commit that was working (old commit builds) and still received the same error
3. Used a different expo account to run the build and produced the same error